# How to make non-blocking http request in go lang?

Tags: asynchronous, go, request

This is my 2nd day of learning go lang and I'm trying to figure out how to make non-blocking http request.

I'm using gin framework and I have very simple code as below.

```
func main() {
    r := gin.Default()

    r.GET("test", func(c *gin.Context){
        request := gorequest.New()
        _, body, _ := request.Get("http://tmp.com").End()
        c.JSON(200, body)
    })

    r.Run()
}
```

tmp.com is a local server, which takes 0.5 second to response (I created it for testing)

When I do a simple ab test on the go server with `wrk -t2 -c50 http://127.0.0.1:8080/test`, I get about 8 requests/sec.

It looks like the request is getting blocked.

I've tried to separate the request into a function then call it with "go" to use coroutine, but that simply returned nothing.

My revised code is

```
func makeRequest(c *gin.Context) {
    request := gorequest.New()
    _, body, _ := request.Get("http://tmp.com").End()
    c.JSON(200, body)
}

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()

    r.GET("test", func(c *gin.Context){
        go makeRequest(c)
    })

    r.Run()
}
```

Is there a simple way to make non-blocking request? or what's the best approach in this case?

Comment: Every incoming request is handled in its own goroutine already.

Comment: @zerkms Thank you for the info. I was not able to confirm that on gin's documentation. That makes sense. I guess I don't have to worry about making a single http request async in that case.

Comment: It uses the standard go's `http` to handle requests https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/blob/master/gin.go#L287

Comment: Ignoring error handling and what not, the best approach is in the first snippet.  There's no need for non-blocking in this example.

Comment: @ThunderCat Thank you!

Comment: You can't make this happen if you want to return the response from tmp.com to client back. HTTP is synchronous protocol: the client issues a request and waits for a response.

Comment: All requests are independent of each other. Unless you have external resources hold by any requests... Nothing there to blocks your request..

Answer (score 1):

As answered already, each HTTP request is handled in it's own go routine. HTTP is a natural fit for the request/response pattern. If you really needed to communicate asynchronously over HTTP you could use a callback function. However I would suggest using event based messaging.

Answer (score 0):

that cannot work, as commented, the http protocol is synchronous.

In the op code the response is sent and written, by the underlying framework, before the parallel `makeRequest` function call finished its job.

If the response is ever written to the client, the client must actively refuse it, as this is not a normal behavior for this protocol.

What is unfortunate in OP code is that the `gin` package won t trigger an error if it tries to write on a closed response.